# Web Query on form post

Tags: html, forms, excel

So I have a lot of data in a spreadsheet and I need to take a value (a number) and have it input into a web form within an ordering form that my supplier gave me. So that I can add it to my order. However I have thousands of different reference numbers and need to figure out what the best way to do this is. Is their a script, vbs, or bit of code that can pull these values from a csv file run them into the form return the first set of values and then go back to the form and do this again for ever number until EOF?

here is what the form looks like:

```
<div align=center>
Please enter an item number: <br>
<input type="text" name="search_number" value="" size="10" maxlength="8">
<input TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Go" NAME="Action">
```

here is part of what is returned.... or really the part that I care about keeping/parsing

```
<div id="grids">
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=100% border=0><tr height=30 bgcolor=#FFD700>                             
<td>  
<font face=arial size=-1 color=000000>&nbsp;<b>
Style #5095 - APPLAUSE-LEOTARD (Page 5D)
</b></font></td></tr><tr height=5><td></td></tr></table>
<table> 
<tr><th></th><th>SC</th><th>INT</th><th>MC</th><th>LC</th><th>XLC</th><tr><td></td><td               
align=center><small>$27.95</small></td><td align=center><small>$27.95</small></td><td    
align=center><small>$27.95</small></td><td align=center><small>$27.95</small></td><td   
align=center><small>$31.95</small></td></tr>
<tr><td><small> (001)</small></td>
<td><input type="text" name="stq-5095-2-001" value ="" size="4" maxlength="4" 
onfocus="this.select()"></td>
<td ><input type="text" name="stq-5095-3-001" value ="" size="4" maxlength="4"   
onfocus="this.select()"></td>
<td ><input type="text" name="stq-5095-4-001" value ="" size="4" maxlength="4"    
onfocus="this.select()"></td>
<td ><input type="text" name="stq-5095-5-001" value ="" size="4" maxlength="4"    
onfocus="this.select()"></td>
<td ><input type="text" name="stq-5095-6-001" value ="" size="4" maxlength="4"  
onfocus="this.select()"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In the end what I would like to see from each returned value is the Style Number (which i searched for),which sizes it has... and the price for each into a spreasheet. Here is what it returns right now. Had to do photobucket share so that I could post this bc stack overflow requires me to have reputation of 10 before I can post images.

```
http://s1159.photobucket.com/albums/p622/dcolnar/
```

I just need the values and the price. It also returns results below that which are close matches Style #5095F, Style #5095S, However for these I have their own row in spreadsheet. So search will return them anyway. So no need to copy these values here.

Once I have that information I need to return to the previous page (i just use back key on browser) and submit the next value in the form. (need to delete the value that is in there... or dependin on how you do it... just use new value for submission)

IF you are able to give me the code or give me information on the best way to go about getting these value that would be great. I really wish my vendor would just send me a copy of their database table....would be so much easier. I have to login to use this tool, they have provided but once logged in I don't have to relogin to make multiple searches. I am only asked to resubmit login credentials when i close my browser (ends session)

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: What is the "method" for the query form (POST or GET?) Does the number you query appear in the URL of the results page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use python to automate this process:

1. Use the python module `openpyxl` to extract data from the spreadsheet.
2. Use the python module `Mechanize` to automate web navigation and form completion and submission.
3. Use the python module `BeautifulSoup` to parse the returned HTML and get the data you need.

Other alternatives:

1. Perl has similar modules to the python modules described above.
2. Powershell
3. Other dot Net languages